# External file with multiple numbers per line Java

Tags: java

I need help reading an external file that has more than one number per line. Here is the external data file:

1 1

2 3

3 5

4 7

5 2

6 4

1 6

2 8

3 1

4 3

5 5

6 7

1 8

2 1

3 2

4 3

5 4

6 5

I read it in by using

```
 public class Prog435a
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
       Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Super Mario\\Documents\\java programs\\Prog435\\Prog435a.in"));
       while(kbReader.hasNext())
       {
           int data = kbReader.nextInt();
           System.out.println(data);
       }
    }
}
```

However, it prints out the file with each number line by line. So instead of appearing in columns, it appears in a single column. How can I get this to print out in two columns as shown above? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Read two values at a time and print them separate by a space.

Answer (score 3):

Loop by line. Call `nextInt()` two times per line.

```
while(kbReader.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(kbReader.nextInt() + " " + kbReader.nextInt());
}
```